# How can i access /connect/* in spring-social?, How can i active connectionController?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

I have a problem now.

To use Spring social, I added the library to Maven. like this

```
    <!-- Spring Social -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Initially I did the spring-social configuration.

```
enter code here@Configuration
public class SocialConfig {

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
      ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new 
  ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
      registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
          "1453476681579886","7e2a4d42b2ca06bf6a571fbb27cf291d"));
      return registry;
  }


}
```

However, I encountered a 404 error.
next

```
<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
<property name="connectionFactories">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
            <constructor-arg value="23124124143213" />
            <constructor-arg value="safsadf342131qeqweqeweeasd1ad" />               
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

It was the same.

Mapped "{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[GET]}","{[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[POST]}" logs do not pop up either.
How can i active connectionController?
help me!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was just a version issue.
I changed the version and it worked.